# C++ std::ofstream class members

Tags: c++, stdout

first time contributor, but I believe I've checked the past posts correctly and do not find a solution that works.  I am using Visual Studio 2012...

Essentially, all I want to do is stream output to a log file owned by an object.  I have no hang-ups about how precisely this should be achieved but nothing in the archives works.

As I understand it, this accepted solution *ought* to work:

```
#include <fstream>
// classA.h
class A {
private:
    std::ofstream * _logfile;
public:
    A(void);
    void dosomething(void) const;
}
```

and

```
// classA.cpp
#include classA.h
A::A(void) : _logfile(0) {
    std::ofstream output("logfile.txt",std::ofstream::app);
    _logfile = &output;
}

A::dosomething(void) {
    *_logfile << "Print something" << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
// main.cpp
int main() {
A a = new A();
a->dosomething();
}
```

This compiles ok but just hangs.  Most probably, I guess, because output disappears at ctor end.  What's a good robust way to achieve this functionality?  Other StackOverflow suggestions read result in compiler errors...

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: `A a = new A();` ? I don't believe you when you say this code compiles.

Comment: Yes, sorry missing * and that's not the only error either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code has undefined behaviour as `_logfile` is a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) after `A` has been constructed because it is taking the address of `output` which is a local variable defined in the constructor of `A`: when `A`'s constructor completes, `output` is destructed. `_logfile` is then dereferenced in `do_something()`, which is undefined behaviour and is the probable cause of the hang.

To solve, just use a `std::ofstream` member and make `A` non-copyable (as streams are not copyable, but are movable):

```
class A {
private:
    std::ofstream _logfile;
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
public:
    A() : _logfile("logfile.txt",std::ofstream::app) {}
    void dosomething()
    {
        _logfile << "Print something" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, hmjd, this works at last.  Frankly, though, I don't understand the (reason for the) necessity of making A non-copyable.  Any chance you can point me towards an explanation?

Comment: @loadsamates, if a class has a non-copyable member then the containing class is also non-copyable.

Comment: Has this changed in any way? Because when I tried a code like this i checked with is_open() and it returned *true* in the constructor and *false* in other functions within the class...

Comment: nvm, it seems like the problem lies somewhere else in my code, as my object is being destroyed right after it's construction. What's also weird, but another topic.

Answer (score 2):

You have a pointer to an object on a stack, it will be deleted after the constructor is finished:

```
#include classA.h
A::A(void) : _logfile(0) {
    std::ofstream output("logfile.txt",std::ofstream::app);//it's on the stack
    _logfile = &output;//pointer to an object on the stack
}

A::dosomething(void) {
    *_logfile << "Print something" << std::endl;
}
```

better use:

```
std::ofstream _logfile;
```

and init it in the initialization list of the constructor:

```
A::A(void) : _logfile("logfile.txt",std::ofstream::app){}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you are setting `_logfile` to the address of a local `ofstream` object.  When the constructor returns, this object is destroyed.  `_logfile` is left as a dangling pointer, and your operations on it in the `dosomething` function result in undefined behavior.  Why don't you just declare `_logfile` as a regular `ofstream` object, instead of a pointer?